# Function PubSub Schedule does not run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My project is on the Blaze plan, I have 3 schedule, right?

**My function:**

```
exports.Test =  functions.pubsub.schedule('every monday 21:45').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('Test');
    return null;
});
```

I also tried with the following cron:

- 46 21 * * 2,4

It worked using [AppEngine's cron.yaml](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=2) syntax that is quoted in the documentation

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

worked: **'every 5 minutes'**

But it does not meet the requirement.

**I need a scheduler that runs every Tuesday and Wednesday at 23:59**

Once again failed

[image]
[image]

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('20 22 * * 1,2,3').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('Test');
    return null;
});
```

*I need to add a timezone?*

How it worked for me:

**Just adding timeZone, I found no other way.**

```
exports.scheduledFunction4 = functions.pubsub.schedule('56 22 * * 1,2,3').timeZone('America/Sao_Paulo').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('Test');
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('59 23 * * 2,3').timeZone('YOUR REGION').onRun((context) => {
  // code ehere
  return null;
});
```

I recommend using [crontab](https://crontab.guru/#59_23_*_*_2,3) for everything cron related.

Best.

Comment: I will test one more time:

Comment: exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('20 22 * * 1,2,3').onRun((context) => {
 // code ehere
 console.log('Test');
 return null;
});